# Trouble with JqueryValidate ; dynamic number of fields

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I’ve got a little problem with the plugin jQueryValidate.

It is really simple: I’d just like to check my form with this plugin and make a small tooltip appearing if a value is wrong or if a field is empty. I use qTip2 for that and it works great!

But the problem is that somewhere in the form, I’ve got a dynamic number of fields where the user has to enter a validation code. I’d like to check if the entered code exists in the database I’m using and show a little tooltip if it’s not.

So, I achieved that but my question is how can I make a “dynamic” rule for this undefined number of fields and use only one PHP file that checks if the code exists in the database?

Here’s my form with standard fields:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="inscription-form" name="inscription-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="text" name="v_nom" id="v_nom" class="defaultInvalid" size=30 tabindex="1" value="nom" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="v_prenom" id="v_prenom" class="defaultInvalid" size=30 tabindex="2" value="pr&eacute;nom"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="v_adresse" id="v_adresse" class="defaultInvalid" size=30 tabindex="3" value="adresse"/><br />
```

[…]

And there I have an undefined number of fields:

```
<input type="text" class="ticket-field" name="v_ticket_1" id="v_ticket_1" size=30 tabindex="9" value="ticket"/>
<input type="text" class="ticket-field" name="v_ticket_2" id="v_ticket_2" size=30 tabindex="10" value="ticket"/>
```

[…]

Here is my JS

```
myForm.validate({
errorClass: "errormessage",
onkeyup: false,
errorClass: 'error',
validClass: 'valid',

rules: {

    v_nom: { required: true, minlength: 2 },
    v_prenom: { required: true, minlength: 2 },
    […]

    v_ticket_1: {
        remote: "includes/deindeal_check_tickets.php",
        async: false
    }
},
messages: {
    v_nom: { defaultInvalid: v_name_msg },
    v_prenom: { defaultInvalid: v_last_name_msg },
    […]

    v_ticket_1 : { remote: "Coupon invalide"}
},
success: function(error) {

    setTimeout(function() {
       myForm.find('.valid').qtip('destroy');
    }, 1);
},

submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
},

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {...
```

And so on...

By now, my PHP file just returns true or false. It’s just a test.

So, how can I define only one rule for all the fields with the class “ticket-field” and use only one other file to check the value? Unfortunately, I couldn’t find a good solution anywhere. Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `add` function of the [rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) method to find and set rules for all your `ticket-field`s.  You can do that after you call validate:

```
myForm.validate({
     //all your options and rules, but exclude anything about v_ticket_1
});

$('.ticket-field').each(function(){
    $(this).rules('add',{
        remote: "includes/deindeal_check_tickets.php",
    });
});
```